# Rounding a value to the nearest 50

Tags: excel, rounding

I want to round values to its nearest 50.
For e.g.

```
121 should get rounded to 100
129 should get rounded to 150
178 should get rounded to 200
165 should get rounded to 150
```

I have tried the following functions...

```
=FLOOR(C629,50)
=FLOOR((C629+50),50)
=CEILING(C631,50)
```

But I am still not getting the results as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the examples you have provided, it appears that you want to move each number to the *nearest* multiple of 50.

This function should accomplish this:

```
=ROUND(C629 / 50 , 0) * 50
```

This works in the following manner for `129`:

1. 129 / 50 = 2.58
2. ROUND(2.58 , 0) = 3
3. 3 * 50 = 150

EDIT: The OP's comment to use the in-built `MROUND` is a much better idea.

Comment: =FLOOR(444/50, 1)*50 ### This will output 400 I expect 450

Comment: =MROUND(589,50) ### is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For clarity, the simplest answer is [`MROUND`](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Mround-Function.html), e.g.:

```
=MROUND(589,50)
```

This solution was [submitted in a comment by shantanuo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895882/rounding-a-value-to-the-nearest-50/3895887#comment4150115_3895887).